# Why can't I access to my local docker-compose from Browser?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I've run my docker-compose file trying to dockerize pgadmin for Postgres but my browser cannot connect to pgadmin on url localhost:8080.

This is the docker-compose file that I am running

```yaml
version: '3'
services:
  db:
    container_name: postgres_container
    image: postgres
    restart: always
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: postgres_db
      POSTGRES_USER: admin
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: secret
      PGDATA: /var/lib/postgresql/data
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    volumes:
      - db-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data

  pgadmin:
    container_name: pgadmin4_container
    image: dpage/pgadmin4:5.5
    restart: always
    environment:
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL: admin@admin.com
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD: secret
      PGADMIN_LISTEN_PORT: 80
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
    volumes:
      - pgadmin-data:/var/lib/pgadmin
volumes:
  db-data:
  pgadmin-data:
```

This is my docker ps

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                           NAMES
c6a6a588f639        dpage/pgadmin4:5.5   "/entrypoint.sh"         3 hours ago         Up 9 minutes        443/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8080->80/tcp   pgadmin4_container
ad6fe3349717        postgres             "docker-entrypoint.s"    3 hours ago         Up 9 minutes        0.0.0.0:5432->5432/tcp          postgres_container
```

When I try to connect to it from browser to localhost:8080 it says Connection attempt failed

Comment: I would suggest to use this image: https://hub.docker.com/_/adminer

Comment: Compose file looks correct. I'd look into other suspects: HSTS cache in the browser (try in different browser, you do not use regularly)? Is the host runing Windows? Then is the WSL network in good shape (other images work fine)? Maybe it's just firewall/antivir settings? Is the db service runinig? Maybe the volumes contain corrupted data, and needs to be recreated?

Answer (score 0):

I am using almost the same docker compose file on Windows 10 with WSL 2 and can connect immediately using Firefox build 100 browser to localhost:8080.
My difference is that the image for pgadmin4 in the compose file is  image: dpage/pgadmin4

- the latest not v5.5

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem. Turns out that DOCKER_HOST variable was set to 192.168.99.100:2376. You can see it by running command `echo $DOCKER_HOST`
I just ran my docker container into this port instead of localhost and everything worked fine.

```
docker run -d -p 192.168.99.100:9411:9411 openzipkin/zipkin
```

And I was able to access my docker container through the browser by url http://192.168.99.100:9411/ Thank you very much everyone